# Do WCF clients/servers check certificate's 

Tags: wcf, certificate

Hopefully the following questions will make some sense

Assume browser `A` wants to establish a SSL connection with web server `B` located at url www.xyz.com. When establishing a connection with `B`, `A` receives from the other end a X.509 certificate `C`. When A receives  B's certificate, it checks certificate's `CN` field  to match server `B's` hostname with domain name specified in certificate's `CN` field ( this matching is done by the browser and not by the underlying SSL connection). If `B's` hostname doesn't match with domain www.xyz.com, then `A` rejects the connection.

a) When WCF client receives a certificate `C` from a WCF service, does it also check `C's` `CN` field to match server's hostname with with domain name specified in `CN` field?

b) And vice-versa - When WCF service receives a certificate `C` from a WCF client, does it also check `C's CN` field to match client's hostname with with domain name specified in `CN` field?

c) If answer to the above questions is yes, then I fail to see how we can use self-signing certificates `SSC` with WCF, since to my knowledge `SSC's CN` field value doesn't match the hostname of a `SSC's` owner

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that a self-signed (root) certificate does not often have a common name that matches a host name, although it is definitely possible, but you can use that self-signed certificate to issue a certificate with the common name that you need, eg. a host name.

Comment: How then can self-signed certificates be used with WCF ( and as far as I know, they can be)? Namelly, even if we put self-signed certificate C ( which client will use to authenticate itself to the server ) inside Trusted people store, WCF will still check CN field when it receives a certificate from client?!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this MSDN entry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx